# Issues with having multiple observables firing off multiple times

Tags: javascript, pagination, ember.js

In Ember.js, I have a Controller property function which calls an json request, and it needs to have multiple observables, as there are multiple conditions where I need to update the json data.

This works great when only one of the properties observed changes, however, when there is a case that multiple properties goes through a change, this is causing the json request to fire off multiple times with the identical request. How can I limit the amount of times that this function fires off to only once?

I kept the question general to have it be applied to other future cases, however, if it is pertinent, the case that I'm using it for is in the case of Pagination, where I need to observe the page index, the page size, the sorted by, and the sort order.

Comment: I'm investigating beginPropertyChanges() and endPropertyChanges() currently. Not sure if this is the correct path.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach would be to set a flag on the controller when it is about to make the request, clear it when the request completes, and check the flag in the observer to decide whether to generate the ajax request.

Comment: I'm gonna try this. Thanks again Luke.